# Read chunked through socket

Tags: java, http, chunked-encoding

For my app I send a http-get request through a socket. Then de website sends a respone, but it is using chunked encoding. Is there a way to download the full data? Maybe I use the wrong way the download the data?

```
BufferedReader rsp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Client.getInputStream()));
```

I have read about 'ChunkedInputStream', but I can't get it work.

Answer (score 2):

Use an HttpURLConnection instead of a Socket. Does it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

specification of chunked encoding is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

in other words read until first `"\r\n"` and parse the number with radix 16 then read until you have read that many bytes and another `"\r\n"` (which is not part of the data) and repeat until the number equals 0

Answer (score 0):

```
    html.replaceAll("\r\n[0-9A-Fa-f ]+\r\n", "");
```

Comment: Unless your data has \r\n